# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) When deployed to cloud, but not on local?

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, serialization

I have a function:

```
def generate_datasource_relations_dataframe():
    """
    Generates pandas dataframe from api response

    """
    # requests lib response object created elsewhere
    response = relations_resp

    # I think this is where the error is happening
    data = json.loads(response.text)

    # I don't think this is relevant to the error
    df = pandas.read_json(json.dumps(data))

    return df
```

That works perfectly when my rest api app is run locally. When deployed to a cloud environment, I get an error (stack trace below) @ `json.loads(response.text)`, I think.

Parsed stack trace:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
at raw_decode (/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py:357)
at decode (/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py:339)
at loads (/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py:354)
at generate_datasource_relations_dataframe (/home/vmagent/app/datawarehouse/util.py:68)
```

I'm confused as to why it works locally and fails when deployed. I don't know containers and hope not to have to implement one right now. And of course, confused as to WHAT is causing the failure.

Any hints?

Comment: Most likely your `response.text` is empty.

Comment: Thanks, I checked that `response.text` is ok when run locally and when deployed to cloud. I re-defined the runtime environment to ensure python 3.7, instead of 3.6, and both local and cloud deployments work now. I don't know what the under-the-hood difference in `raw_decode()` is between the two, though.